# React proper way to pass function as prop with parameters

Tags: reactjs

If I try to pass a function with parameters as props from a `Parent` component to a `Child` component in this way:

```
handleClick={() => handleClick(tiposObjetivos.RENTA_TEMPORAL)}
```

The Child component will re-render everytime Parent is re-render as it creates the function in every render. What is the better way to pass a function as a prop with parameters?

Comment: why would you need to pass params with a function to a child? if the child needs to call that function at a certain time, wouldn't it be better to write a separate function that would call the one you're trying to pass now and pass that separate function to the child instead?

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to pass function as props

```
  <button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
    <button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

The above two lines are equivalent, and use arrow functions and Function.prototype.bind respectively.